# Is there a different master crafting bonus gained from different forges?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I am very curious to know if there is variation between the master crafted bonuses you receive at the forges across the land. Not just by certain equipment tier bonuses, but if it has anything to do with the Forge itself. If anybody has any knowledge towards this endeavor, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

(By the way I will be doing my own research and will post if I find any "promising" differences of bonus-to-Forge location).

Comment: Thank you Montag451. I was careless in my word placement, and punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

I have observed no notices or anything like that. It appears to me that a forge is a forge as far as the game is concerned.